# How to solve Oracle exp error "ORACLE error 1455 encountered " when segments for all tables are available?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

We use exp to backup our database in Oracle 11g. Suddenly, the following error is being reported in the log file:

```
. exporting synonyms
. exporting views
. exporting stored procedures
. exporting operators
. exporting referential integrity constraints
. exporting triggers
. exporting indextypes
. exporting bitmap, functional and extensible indexes
. exporting posttables actions
. exporting materialized views
. exporting snapshot logs
EXP-00008: ORACLE error 1455 encountered
ORA-01455: converting column overflows integer datatype
EXP-00000: Export terminated unsuccessfully
```

I have checked the database for `SEGMENT_CREATED` column for `USER_TABLES`, `USER_INDEXES` and `USER_LOBS` and there are no rows where `SEGMENT_CREATED = 'NO'`.

Found some solutions to export database by turning audit off, using `INDEXES=N` and `STATISTICS=NONE` but I don't want to use those options.

Also, don't want to use `expdp` as I have had problems importing.

The only change somebody did was to create 2 user types recently but I suppose that is not causing the problem.

Suggestions and solutions are highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you at least *try* to do export with additional parameters, `constraints=n indexes=n statistics=none`? Just to see what happens?

Comment: I am trying with statistics=none and will update the result.

Comment: The backup didn't succeed with statistics=none. Any suggestions?

Comment: did `purge recyclebin` and waiting for the backup to complete.

Comment: No kidding! Recyclebin? Who'd say (I wouldn't, obviously). Great, I hope everything will be just fine. Thank you for letting us know!

Comment: Also re-generated statistics: `BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT * 
                FROM all_users
                WHERE username NOT IN ('SYS','SYSDBA') AND username NOT LIKE '%OPS$%')
    LOOP
        dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(rec.username);
    END LOOP;
END;` Will update after the backup completes.

Comment: Didn't work !!! Same error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(

Comment: Exported database using exp and without any row so that I could open it in a text editor, found the following at the very end when the error is being triggered: `METRICEU 7374
METRICSUmaterialized views
METRICEU 7374
METRICSUsnapshot logs           `. The blank spaces are `NULNULNULNULNULNUL`

Comment: Also dropped all materialized view logs and regenerated them and did complete refresh from the remote locations, still the error :-(

Comment: Strange thing is that after dropping all the materialized view logs, the backup succeeded without any errors but without the logs, remote locations are not able to refresh.

Comment: Apparently, EXP causes problems. You said that you can't use EXPDP because of importing problems. What kind of problems? Perhaps they can be fixed easier than EXP problems?